# Saving Excel file of 50k rows using "ClosedXML" NuGet taking a very long time

Tags: c#, .net, excel, nuget, closedxml

I need to save data into an Excel file(.xlsx).
I decided to use "*ClosedXML*" NuGet (v0.95.3) (https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML/) for implementing it, after getting several recommendations on this NuGet from different developers.

Recently I encounter a problem when exporting **50k rows**:

- The saving process alone (after all the data was already added to the file) taking a very long time around **~10 seconds**
- This is without mention that the styling of these rows: font, borders, adjust columns width etc. is taking around **~12 seconds**.
- This without mentioning the fact which its taking me an around ~20 to retrieve and write the data into the file, so all the process in such case taking me **~45 seconds Total** (too way much time!!).

I'm saving the data into a given stream using the "SaveAs()" method, and I already used the "*XLEventTracking.Disabled*" optimization.

Probably, I'm not the first one which dealing with Excel files, so:

1. Is anyone of you is familiar with "*ClosedXML*" NuGet and encounter such problem in the past?
2. Are you using a different NuGet for Excel files? (even if it cost money).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A xlsx file is just compressed xml. You can create a two rows Excel sheet, decompress it, look at the xml and simply generate a text file with the 50,000 rows and compress it.

Comment: ClosedXML keeps an in-memory model of all cells and writes it out to file only when you save. The benefit is that this enables a very useful API to manipulate your spreadsheet, but the disadvantage is the memory footprint. If you just want to dump data into a file, I'd look at other tools that write to file. (I'm a ClosedXML maintainer).

Answer (score 4):

I have used `ClosedXML` for a few years, and I have to admit that the library - as of version `0.95.1` - is pretty much unusable for larger Excel reports. The memory usage/footprint is a disaster. A really large report can easily allocate several gigabytes of RAM.

The performance problems you have seen are linked to `GC` (garbage collection). Looking at the code, you quickly realize that fixing this will require several iterations of improvements.

I would recommend looking at other libraries. Personally, I prefer to use the native [libxlsxwriter](https://github.com/jmcnamara/libxlsxwriter) library. You can easily integrate with it, using [DllImport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute?view=netcore-3.1) interop. For large reports, consider the [Constant Memory](https://libxlsxwriter.github.io/working_with_memory.html) mode. With constant memory, it outperforms `ClosedXML` in terms of both CPU and RAM.

Comment: ClosedXML maintainer here. I'm actually surprised that you say the memory usage as regressed. We've been working on it and round about 0.93 there was a major improvement. If you have a specific use case where it regressed in 0.95.1, please log it on the repo.

Comment: For sure, 0.95.1 was an improvement in many ways. But not enough. Just create a sheet with 100 columns and 100,000+ rows. In my tests, we easily hit 6+ GB RAM usage. With `libxlsxwriter` we kept the RAM usage at 20 MB or so.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with 0.96. Building a spreadsheet with around 100k rows understandably takes a significant time, but it's the SaveAs call that's the real killer and takes up the majority of both time and system resources.